# How to create a different page.tpl.php for different page, if pathauto is active?

Tags: nodes

I am new in drupal 7. I have created a page about us. My url is look like:

http://domain_name/content/about-us

Now I want a different page.tpl.php for this particular page.

Please help how to do this?

Thanks

Prabeen

Answer (score 1):

It is all outlined on the [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) page.
eg. page--node--1.tpl.php